# Unsure why this is generating so many threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm running some tests on a short program I've written.  It runs another program which performs some file operations based on the inputs I give it.  The whole purpose of this program is to break a large packet of work into smaller packets to increase performance (sending 10 smaller packets to 10 versions of the program instead of waiting for the one larger one to execute, simple divide and conquer).

The problem lies in the fact that, while I believe I have limited the number of threads that will be created, the testing messages I have set up indicate that there are many more threads running than there should be.  I'm really uncertain what I did wrong here.

Code snippet:

```
if (finish != start){
    if (sizeOfBlock != 0){
            num_threads = (finish - start)/sizeOfBlock + 1;
        }
    else{
        num_threads = (finish-start) + 1;
    }
    if (num_threads > 10){  // this should limit threads to 10 at most
        num_threads == 10;
    }
    else if (finish == start){
        num_threads = 1;
    }
}



    threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", i);
        s = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, &MaxNum);
        if (s != 0)
            printf("error in pthread_create\n");
        if (s==0)
            activethreads++;
    }
    while (activethreads > 0){
        //printf("active threads: %d\n", activethreads);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
```

Comment: Well, maybe you should print out the value of num_threads, no?

Comment: You malloc a number of threads, but I don't see a free().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is useless:

```
if (num_threads > 10){  // this should limit threads to 10 at most
    num_threads == 10
}
```

`num_threads == 10` compares `num_threads` to `10` and then throws that away. You want assignment instead:

```
if (num_threads > 10){  // this should limit threads to 10 at most
    num_threads = 10;
}
```

Also, there are numerous `;` missing in your code, in the future, please try to provide a self contained example of code that compiles.

Comment: sorry about that, I added brackets to make the if statements clearer (they were previously just single lines).  Thank you for pointing out the equivalency vs assignment notation, I must have overlooked that ten times.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus No problem, it happens to the best ;)